# max-height is not working, scroll is showing up but the div is getting higher

Tags: html, css

I am currently facing a problem with the max-height property in my stylesheets, i have div with the '.background' class in which elements are added dynamically, i set the max-height and height of the div to 80%; the scroll is showing up as i desired, but the div is not preserving it's max-height, is still getting taller when elements are added.

**HTML**

```
<!--Info Navigation, this is used to select what information the user wants to see.-->
<div class="info">
    <div class="info-tab tab-active"><p>General</p></div><div class="info-tab"><p>Appointments</p></div><div class="info-tab"><p>Exams</p></div><div class="info-tab"><p>Charges</p></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- General Information of the patient-->
    <div class="general-info">
        <div class="general">
            <h2>General</h2>
            <div class="title">General Information</div>
            <p>Id Card Number: {{patient.id_number}}</p>
            <p class="name">First Name: {{patient.first_names}}</p>
            <p class="name">Last Name: {{patient.last_names}}</p>
            <p>Gender: {{patient.get_gender_display}}</p>
            <p>Birthday: {{patient.birthday|date:"d M, Y"}}</p>
            <p>Age: {{patient.age}}</p>
            <p>Phone Number: {{patient.phone_number}}</p>
            <p>Email: {{patient.email}}</p>
            <p>Civil Status: {{patient.get_civil_status_display}}</p>
            <p>Origin: {{patient.get_origin_display}}</p>
            <p>Residence: {{patient.get_residence_display}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="background">
            <h2>Background</h2>
            <div class="title">Allergies</div>
            {%if patient.allergies%}
                {%for allergy in patient.allergies.all%}
                    <p>{{forloop.counter}}. {{allergy.allergy_type}} - {{allergy.about}}</p>
                {%endfor%}
            {%endif%}
            <div class="title">Antecedents</div>
            {%if patient.antecedents%}
                {%for antecedent in patient.antecedents.all%}
                    <p>{{forloop.counter}}. {{antecedent.antecedent}} - {{antecedent.info}}</p>
                {%endfor%}
            {%endif%}
            <div class="title">Insurance</div>
            {%if patient.insurance%}
                <p>Insurance Carrier: {{patient.insurance.insurance_carrier}}</p>
                <p>Insurance Type: {{patient.insurance.insurance_type}}</p>
                <p>Expiration Date: {{patient.insurance.expiration_date}}</p>
            {%endif%}
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*##################################################### Body #########################################################*/

body{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#title{
    position: absolute;
}

/*##################################################### Wrapper ######################################################*/

.wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
    grid-gap: 1%;
    margin-top: 6%;
}

.general-info{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 49.5% 49.5%;
    grid-gap: 1%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

/*Div i am trying to set the maximun height to*/
.background{
    height: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.general-info h2{
    margin-left: 45%;
}

.filterable{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 79% 20%;
    grid-gap: 1%;
}

.no-data{
    margin-left: 45%;
}

a{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.title{
    padding: 10px;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: #6082AD;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 5%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: you shoud use some fixed measure (px, rem, vh...) for max-height, or things get complicated when you rely on parents' percentage

Comment: Wow, it's surprising how this solved my entire problem! Thanks, so much, is this like a rule? Or it's for convenience to use fixed measures in max-height properties?

Comment: @LuisRodriguez see my answer, it's because you're telling the browser the height of this is X% of its parent, and that cascades all the way up, but each parent would need to have some height set, and if none of them have a fixed measurement then you're really saying "X% of whatever the content dictates the height should be".

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: It's growing because you're using percentage based heights and the height of its parent elements is not defined therefore they grow as more content is added, so it becomes 80% of the new height of its parent element.

Based on the way you have this layout setup, I would recommend fixing the height of the body to the viewport `body{height: 100vh}`

Then both the `.wrapper` and `.general-info` elements will need to have their heights restricted, so that your target element `.background` will be restricted to 80% of whatever you restrict those to. (You don't necessarily have to restrict `.wrapper` if you just restrict `.general-info`, but if you're using all percentages each element will always be X% of its parent element, and if there is no parent element that has a non-percentage based height that element will be allowed to grow which will effect the rest of the percentage based elements.) - I hope that makes sense.

You could skip most of that and just restrict `.background` using a non-percentage value like `.background{max-height: 50vh}` (50% of the viewport height).